# How to manage Layout of an individual item ListLayout

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter

Kind time of the day. There is such a task. Output ListView and in it in each element of the given data with ArrayList. But there is one nuance. By default (default), each element is shown only in half (it consists of 2 layouts for one of which is visibility = gone), and by clicking on this item it should be shown completely (both visibility = visible), after a second click hide the extra part. It's clear that I'll create a custom adapter and put data into it, but how do I expand and collapse exactly the element I'm tapping into, and not the last one? Please tell me how to implement this.
If something is not clear in my explanation see the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTG4t.jpg).

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/layout_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_two"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Code:

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // используем созданные, но не используемые view
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_item, parent, false);
layoutParent = (LinerLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.layout_parent);
text1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
text2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);

        Product p = getProduct(position);
        text1.setText(p.getName());
        text2.setText(p.getLastName());

        layoutParent.setOnClicListner(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(layiutTwo.getVisibiliti() == View.VISIBLE){
                    layiutTwo.setVisibiliti().View.GONE;
                } else {
                    layiutTwo.setVisibiliti().View.VISIBLE;
                }
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You show us what you've got (code / layout file(s)), we show you how to take the next step :)

Comment: And where is you findViewById or smth. As you said that "... and not the last one" I suppose you create you views as global fields and after adapter finish his job this fields binded to last item. So we need more details.

Comment: Have you considered using the ExpandableListView: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html

Comment: No, the design decision is important.

Comment: @Pavel Zlotarenchuk have you tried to replace findViewById to getView?

Comment: I'm sure that's not the problem.
How to set parameters for a specific position.

Comment: All right, that's better. Your OnClickListener changes the visibility of some *layiutTwo*. Where do you get that from? I can't see it in your code elsewhere.